# Creating Several New Scaled Variables at Once (additive or mean)

Tags: r, loops, variable-assignment

Say I want to create a two new variables - "mean1" and "mean2" - whereby: "mean1" is the average of "var1" and "var2" and "mean2" is the average of "var3", "var4", and "var5. Here is an example data frame:

```
set.seed(23424)
df <- data.frame(var1 = runif(5, 0, 5),
                 var2 = runif(5, 0, 5),
                 var3 = runif(5, 0, 5),
                 var4 = runif(5, 0, 5),
                 var5 = runif(5, 0, 5))
```

I COULD brute force it with something like:

```
df$mean1 <- rowMeans(df[,1:2])
df$mean2 <- rowMeans(df[,3:5])
```

But if I had to do stuff like this a lot, it would get tedious and clunky. It would be nice if there was a way to do this more efficiently. When I try to use loops or apply statements for this, it never goes correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We could come up with lots of different ways to do this, I bet, but when you have todo this for much bigger problems, how do you imagine you will identify the variables you want to contribute to each mean?  Will you have an external list or something?

Comment: I was imagining a list probably. I could do something like this, but it still seems a bit clunky. Maybe I need to work with what I have though lol.

`code
    l <- as.list(df[,1:2], df[,3:5])
    vars <- c("mean1", "mean2")
    means <- lapply(l, mean)

    for(i in 1:length(means)){
      df[,6:7] <- l[i]
      names(df)[c(6:7)] <- vars
    }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this - where you have the variables you want to aggregate in a list.  I assume there's probably a better fully tidy way of doing this, but this works:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(23424)
df <- data.frame(var1 = runif(5, 0, 5),
                   var2 = runif(5, 0, 5),
                   var3 = runif(5, 0, 5),
                   var4 = runif(5, 0, 5),
                   var5 = runif(5, 0, 5))
l <- list(mean1 = c("var1", "var2"), 
          mean2 = c("var3", "var4", "var5"))
  

for(i in 1:length(l)){
  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(!!sym(names(l)[i]) := rowMeans(cur_data()[,l[[i]]]))
}
df
#>       var1      var2      var3      var4      var5    mean1     mean2
#> 1 1.892178 0.2488837 4.3203682 2.6517051 1.2454473 1.070531 2.7391735
#> 2 1.390501 2.9131956 0.8851525 3.9931125 1.8389664 2.151848 2.2390771
#> 3 3.131567 4.8579541 0.1950122 3.9789130 4.6969826 3.994761 2.9569693
#> 4 4.425019 2.5628706 0.6257656 0.1144681 1.8303231 3.493945 0.8568523
#> 5 2.621068 4.7636304 1.2762756 1.1706242 0.1881539 3.692349 0.8783512
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this, I came up with something similar. Still a bit clunky, but sometimes we deal with what we got. Thanks for this.

`code 
l <- as.list(df[,1:2], df[,3:5])
vars <- c("mean1", "mean2")
means <- lapply(l, mean)

for(i in 1:length(means)){
  df[,6:7] <- l[i]
  names(df)[c(6:7)] <- vars
}
`

Side question @DaveArmstrong: How're you getting your code to display nicely in the comments? I'm trying all kinds of stuff based on the "Help" button in the bottom right and all I get is the ugly thing I put here. Sorry, I'm new to contributing :(

Comment: If you use the `reprex` package, you can wrap your code in `reprex::reprex({<<code>>})` and when you run it, it will put in your clipboard the markdown code you can paste in your answer.

Comment: Awesome! Fortunately, it seems that this issue only arises on comments to comments. Comments to OP are pretty straightforward. Thanks again.